# Summarise conditional sum adding up to 0

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use dplyr to group by an summarize users comments that on post consider as "engaged"

the database is user-post-is_engaged-comments (char-char-bool-num) and looks like this:

```
user_id  post_id is_engaged comments
 user1     post1   TRUE        3
 user1     post2   FALSE       1
 user1     post2   FALSE       NA
```

So I want to summarise the number of comments that happen on engaged post.

**So I do this typically**

```
df_user_post %>%
 summarise(
    total_users = n_distinct(user_id[is_engaged == TRUE]),
    total_comments_on_engaged_posts = sum(comments[is_engaged == TRUE],na.rm = TRUE)
         )
```

I get:

```
total_users_on_engaged post  total_comments_on_engaged_posts
            586                             0
```

The first number (586) is correct, the second one is not.

I know for a fact there are comments on engaged posts on my dataframe, so I was wondering why would it add up to 0? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I run your `summarise` line on the sample data it returns `1` and `3`, which seems to be working as expected. Can you provide a reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: You can also do `sum(comments * is_engaged, na.rm=T)`. The logical will be coerced to an integer of 0/1 and feed into your sum just fine. That being said, if a row's value in either column is NA, the result will be NA and drop from your sum. But I guess in the above case it shouldn't be an issue